# How to create an array that can be accessed according to its indices in Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I am trying to solve the following problem via a Finite Difference Approximation in Python using NumPy:

$u_t = k \, u_{xx}$, on $0 < x < L$ and $t > 0$;

$u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0$;

$u(x,0) = f(x)$.

I take $u(x,0) = f(x) = x^2$ for my problem.

Programming is not my forte so I need help with the implementation of my code. Here is my code (I'm sorry it is a bit messy, but not too bad I hope):

```
    ## This program is to implement a Finite Difference method approximation
## to solve the Heat Equation, u_t = k * u_xx,
## in 1D w/out sources & on a finite interval 0 < x < L. The PDE
## is subject to B.C: u(0,t) = u(L,t) = 0,
## and the I.C: u(x,0) = f(x).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# definition of initial condition function  
def f(x):
    return x^2

# parameters    
L = 1
T = 10
N = 10
M = 100
s = 0.25

# uniform mesh
x_init = 0
x_end = L
dx = float(x_end - x_init) / N

#x = np.zeros(N+1)
x = np.arange(x_init, x_end, dx)
x[0] = x_init

# time discretization
t_init = 0
t_end = T
dt = float(t_end - t_init) / M

#t = np.zeros(M+1)
t = np.arange(t_init, t_end, dt)
t[0] = t_init

# Boundary Conditions
for m in xrange(0, M):
    t[m] = m * dt

# Initial Conditions
for j in xrange(0, N):
    x[j] = j * dx

# definition of solution to u_t = k * u_xx
u = np.zeros((N+1, M+1)) # NxM array to store values of the solution

# finite difference scheme
for j in xrange(0, N-1):
    u[j][0] = x**2 #initial condition

for m in xrange(0, M):
    for j in xrange(1, N-1):
        if j == 1:
            u[j-1][m] = 0 # Boundary condition
        else: 
            u[j][m+1] = u[j][m] + s * ( u[j+1][m] - #FDM scheme
            2 * u[j][m] + u[j-1][m] )
        else:
            if j == N-1:
                u[j+1][m] = 0 # Boundary Condition

print u, t, x
#plt.plot(t, u)
#plt.show()
```

So the first issue I am having is I am trying to create an array/matrix to store values for the solution. I wanted it to be an `NxM` matrix, but in my code I made the matrix `(N+1)x(M+1)` because I kept getting an error that the index was going out of bounds. Anyways how can I make such a matrix using `numpy.array` so as not to needlessly take up memory by creating a `(N+1)x(M+1)` matrix filled with zeros?

Second, how can I "access" such an array? The real solution `u(x,t)` is approximated by `u(x[j], t[m])` were `j` is the jth spatial value, and `m` is the mth time value. The finite difference scheme is given by:

```
u(x[j],t[m+1]) = u(x[j],t[m]) + s * ( u(x[j+1],t[m]) - 2 * u(x[j],t[m]) + u(x[j-1],t[m]) )
```

(See here for the [formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method#Explicit_method%20%22formulation))

I want to be able to implement the Initial Condition `u(x[j],t[0]) = x**2` for all values of `j = 0,...,N-1`. I also need to implement Boundary Conditions `u(x[0],t[m]) = 0 = u(x[N],t[m])` for all values of `t = 0,...,M`. Is the nested loop I created the best way to do this? Originally I tried implementing the I.C. and B.C. under two different for loops which I used to calculate values of the matrices `x` and `t` (in my code I still have comments placed where I tried to do this)

I think I am just not using the right notation but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation for NumPy how to "call" such an array so at to iterate through each value in the proposed scheme. Can anyone shed some light on what I am doing wrong?

Any help is very greatly appreciated. This is not homework but rather to understand how to program FDM for Heat Equation because later I will use similar methods to solve the Black-Scholes PDE.

EDIT: So when I run my code on line 60 (the last "else" that I use) I get an error that says invalid syntax, and on line 51 (`u[j][0] = x**2` #initial condition) I get an error that reads "setting an array element with a sequence." What does that mean?

Comment: "How to create an array that can be accessed according to its indices in Numpy?" - that's ... any array. You've got some bug somewhere and you're looking in the wrong places for it.

Comment: Is my notation `u[j][m]` acceptable though? For the purpose of iterating over the loop?

Comment: `u[j, m]` is generally preferred, since `u[j][m]` doesn't generalize to `u[:][m]`.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. And `u[:][m]` is that the slice notation? One person told me (in a previous post I made) that I can set the Initial Conditions via `u[:,0] = x**2` ... Can this be done for the boundary conditions in a similar manner by `u[0, :] = 0` and `u[N, :] = 0` ? Also do I need a loop for that or is the slice notation built into the code for `numpy.array`? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Not only *can* you set the initial conditions with `u[:, 0] = x**2`, you almost *need* to. Your current code is trying to stuff an entire array into each cell of `u`'s first column.

Comment: I think you need to learn some basic `numpy` coding first.  Confusion over indexing notation like `[:][m[` suggests that you are trying to program this problem without first understanding the basics.